# What kind of connector is populated on this PCB?

Tags: connector

I've been looking for some sort of leaf spring contact but haven't come across this double-sided variety. Does this look like a COTS connector, or is it just a custom formed piece of copper?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of contact arrangement is found in systems where one part is steady in combination with a rotating part. In almost all occasion these arrangement are custom made for the intended purpose.

The double spring contacts are only introduced for both prolonged and reliable service. The contacts run frequently on a brass ring and are made of phosfor bronze.

Looking at the contact arrangement. Two contact sets are in 3 fold and one set is only two fold. The set is most probably used to transfer mains (black and white) to a rotating part while maintaining also a dependable frame contact (green)

In simple setup's (without the earth connection) you find this kind of arrangement in vacuum cleaners, etc.

Comment: Any idea what actual surface mount piece that is? Does that seem like a COTS part that you've seen before?

Comment: I have seen such parts before but always in dedicated environments